# converting a php loop to twig loop

Tags: php, twig

Title says so^

in php you could easily do

```
for($page = 1; $page <= num_of_pages; $page)
```

in twig, I am attemtping to do an iterating loop but I'm failing hard.

here's my attempt, but why does it only show 1 row instead of 3

```
{% for i in page .. num_pages if(i <= num_pages) %}
```

**PS**
(total items = 15)

page returns 3
(5 rows per page)
num_pages returns 3

Comment: What are the values of your variables (`page` & `num_pages`)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
{% for i in 0..items|length %}
```

[reference](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use following twig functions :

- `loop.index`  The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
- `loop.length` The number of items in the sequence

```html
{% for page in pages %}
    <!-- page title-->
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <!-- page content -->
    <p>{{ page.content }}</p>
    <!-- pagination -->
    <p>page {{ loop.index }} / {{ pages.length }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```